# Azure Active Directory Error - Application is not authorized to make application on-behalf-of calls

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, on-behalf-of

How can I resolve the "AADSTS7000113: Application [Id] is not authorized to make application on-behalf-of calls" error in Azure Active Directory?

Is there some settings I need to change for this application in the Azure Active Directory? In order to give it permission to make On-behalf-of calls for a specific user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Delegated Permissions for Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCcZl.png)

In the Azure Portal, I've tried adding the user to the "Users and groups" and "Owners" lists of the Application but I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: Which service is your application trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your app delegated permissions in order to use an on-behalf-of token

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/secure-sample-application